# Will Intel® Desktop Board D975XBX2 fit inside Thermaltake Armor+ Case

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, computer-building, case

I have this motherboard `Intel® Desktop Board D975XBX2` CPU Quad Core

I want to Buy [Thermaltake Armor+ case](http://www.thermaltake.com/product_info.aspx?PARENT_CID=C_00000090&id=C_00000091&name=Armor%2B&ovid)

With powerSupply  Aerocool [E85-700](http://www.aerocool.com.tw/psu/psu_e85-700.htm)

Will those three work because i have put components from my Older case which has less power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should fit without problems, and it looks like the case also includes the ability to move the separator to accommodate even larger PSUs.

Comment: Will adding more devices to motherboard can cause any damagae to motherboard or its just issue with with Power supply . Will it be easy to dissassemble the Old motherboard and fit in this case for me

Comment: When adding / taking away components, you can always damage either the component or the motherboard if you are not careful. As long as your current case follows a standard (e.g. atx, matx or a few others - listed on the case page) it should fit fine - the only exceptions would be weird custom made sizes you usually see on smaller form factor machines.

Comment: ACtually i could not configure how many IDE HD power cables are there on That PSU. or can i convert SATA Power to IDE power cable

Comment: You can't convert SATA to IDE (well, never seen an adapter that way round) but it looks like it has 2x standard ones.